# Question about equlaity of two language, simple but tricky.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, formal-languages, regular-language

I found the following question tricky:

If $A$ is a language, when will $A^*=A^+$?

By definition,

$$A^* = \bigcup^{\infty}_{i=0}A^i = A^0 \cup A^1 \cup A^2 \cup \cdots$$

$$A^+ = \bigcup^{\infty}_{i=1}A^i =A^1 \cup A^2 \cup \cdots$$

Also, $A^0=\{\epsilon\}$

So, $A^* = A^+$ if and only if $\{\epsilon\} \cup A^+=A^+$. I feel like this can be simplified further.

For example, I can claim that if $A=\{\epsilon \} $, then $A^*=A^+$.But I am not sure. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think you're right in that $A$ must be the empty language to satisfy what you want.

Comment: Languages are subsets of the natural numbers, correct?

Comment: @IanColey Thanks for your comment. Except for the empty one, I want to ask if you see any other cases where $A^*=A^+$?

Comment: Where you wrote $\displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A^n$, might you have meant either $\displaystyle \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A^i$ or $\displaystyle\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A^n$ (two different ways of writing the same thing, but different from what you wrote)?

Comment: @MichaelHardy oh, that's a typo, thanks for pointing out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $A^*=A^+$.  By definition, $\varepsilon$ is in $A^*$, so it's in $A^+$.  Therefore $\varepsilon$ is in $A$ or $A^2$ or. . .  But this just means that $\varepsilon\in A$.  The converse is easy to prove, so
$$A^*=A^+\quad\hbox{if and only if}\quad \varepsilon\in A\ .$$

Comment: The converse side is not quite obvious, I will do : Assume that $\varepsilon\in A$, we need to show that $A^*=A^+$. Since $\varepsilon\in A$, we know that $\varepsilon$ is in $A \cup A^2 \cup ...$, which implies that $\varepsilon \in A^+$.  Hence, $A^+ = \{\varepsilon\} \cup A^+ = A^*$    IS this a clear way to prove the converse? Thanks a lot @David

Comment: @y123lin, looks OK but isn't this even easier? - if $\varepsilon\in A$ we have $A=\{\varepsilon\}\cup A$, so $A^+=A\cup A^2\cup\cdots=\{\varepsilon\}\cup A\cup A^2\cup\cdots=A^*$.

Comment: Ha, no wonder you said the converse side is easy. And yes, your version is very concise. Thanks for your help!